# deleting JSON records using JsonDataObjects

Tags: json, delphi

I'm using the TJsonDataObjects Delphi component (https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects). I am using it as the data store for what is is displayed in a editable TreeView. In the treeview I store the "path" using a JsonPath string. When the user modifies the values in the Treeview, the path property allows me locate the record by path and modify it via the component path property.

My issue is when a user wants to delete a record, I need to remove it from the JSON file. It does note seem like there is a simple way to do this via its "path. I expect I could trim off the item from the path to gets it parent and then delete it by "name" or "index" if an array. I was hoping there might just be an easier way before I start to code this up.

On a similar node, I didn't find any way to extract the text path of a given item. While it can modify or locate a node by path, there does not seem to be a way to get the actual path so I'm doing that manually as I parse the JSON file (yuck). Anyone have a better solution?

For example, this is the path of the "value" property in the JSON below: Level1.Level2.Level3

```
{
  "Level1": {
    "Level2": {
      "Level3": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

In TJsonDataObjects you can set the path with:

```
Json.Path['Level1.Level2.Level3'] := "value";
//or
Json['Level1']['Level2']['Level3'] := "value";
```

Or retrieve it with:

```
prop := Json.Path['Level1.Level2.Level3'];
// or
prop := Json['Level1']['Level2']['Level3'];
```

So if you want to remove Level3, it would be nice if there was some simple function like Json.DeletePath('Level1.Level2.Level3');. As far as I can tell, there is nothing that does this. Since this is a very complex unit, I thought someone might have an easy answer that I overlooked.  I have coded a way around this (as described above).

As to the second question, while you can access a value by its path, there is no function to "return" a path from a given node. And yes, I can and do build it as I go along, it would be handy as that way it remains consistent in its format of the JsonPath.

Comment: Could you put an input json example and what is the result of 'path' to locate the record?

Comment: But it's difficult to find a general solution. In [mORMot](https://synopse.info/files/html/api-1.18/SynCommons.html#TDOCVARIANTDATA) you can delete this item with this code:
 
`Json := _Json(CurrentJson);
P := TDocVariantData(Json).GetPVariantByPath('Level1.Level2');
  TDocVariantData(P^).Delete('Level3');`  But, if the node is an array?